# When not all your functions are polymorphic

Tags: java

From an old exam with no solutions:

Given this code....

```
import java.util.*;

public class AClass {
    private int f(List<Integer> list){
        int i = 0;
        //Something useful
        return i;
    }
    public int g() {
        List<Integer> myList = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        return f(myList);
    }   
}
```

Note that the method `f` is polymorphic, i.e. it can be passed any implementation of the interface List. On the other hand, the method `g` is not.  As it constructs the object `myList`, it cannot do this without knowing its type. Consequently, it cannot be polymorphic. Our code contains many methods suffering from the same problem. We aim to make our code polymorphic.

1. What is the name of the standard solution to this problem?
2. Describe it in this case

Answer (score 2):

1. **Loose coupling** There are many ways to solve that problem among them: program to interfaces and apply [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)
2. Method `g()` is tightly coupled to `LinkedList` because the method is explicitly instantiating that object hence tight to that class. If you want to for example use an `ArrayList` you need to open the class and explicitly modify the method and potentially introduce bugs. Additionally, you will probably need to retest and document. On the other hand method `f()` is way more flexible because you can just pass the collection you need and the method has no notion about the concrete implementation you are passing keeping in that way your method closed.

Comment: 1. Alternatively: Programming to the Interface. Loose coupling is more encompassing.

Comment: Nice answer. It's always better to use the interface (`List`) you need rather than the concrete implementation (`LinkedList`, `ArrayList` etc). You can always use the class instead later on if you need to use methods specific to it that weren't defined in the interface.

Comment: Well you can inject something like `Provider<List<Integer>>`, but the Quote `All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection. ...except for the problem of too many layers of indirection.` comes to mind here ;)

Comment: @Bartzilla - calling `new LinkedList()` is NOT tight coupling, that is called making an instance of List. Tight coupling would be passing LinkedList into f().

Comment: @slugmandrew - how do you make an instance of `List` without calling `new <some impl here>List()`? Look at `java.util.Array.asList(T...)`, it calls `return new ArrayList<>(a)`;

Comment: @ike_love No it is not an instance of List. List is an interface and you cannot instantiate interfaces. You are making an instance of LinkedList and therefore that method is tightly coupled to it. If you could inject any instance into a List parameter you could pass any object that implements List and hence decoupled g and f from LinkedList.

Comment: @Bartzilla - no, loose coupling has nothing to do with how you create your instance of a List as long as the interface and not concrete type is used on the left side of the assignment. Loose coupling comes into play when you pass that instance into another method, that's where you get the benefits of it. Injecting an instance simply moves the decision for which List implementation to use from your code to the injector code, `new <some list impl>List()` will still be called somewhere.

Comment: @ike_love You clearly don't understand the concept of DI. First off how can you create an instance of List? you can't! List is an interface. DI is exactly that!! Externalizing instantiation of objects which are likely to change (e.g factories, ..), so you can keep your tested, documented and compiled classes from having to maintain them. In this case LinkedList is likely to change what happens if you want another type of list? Oh well! you will need to open this class and modify it and potentially break it. And this is exactly where you are wrong! I would suggest you to read a good book on DI.

Answer (score 0):

```
Consequently, it cannot be polymorphic. Our code contains many methods suffering from the same problem. We aim to make our code polymorphic.
```

What do you mean by that? Please provide an examples. The only way to make this code more generic is to use `Collection` or `Iterable` instead of `List`, but I'd say that's an overkill in terms of loose coupling.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the solution in this case would be to create an `Abstract Factory Pattern`.

For example, we'd create a new class called `AClassCreator` and have a method `createAClass(List<?> list)` where the parameter is a subclass of list.